# Flask server not open to local network in windows, host=0.0.0.0 not working

Tags: windows, python-3.x, rest, flask

Flask server not visible from local network, I have done the app.run(host="0.0.0.0") but still wathever is not my local machine is not able to see it.

```
* Serving Flask app "MainBot" (lazy loading)

* Environment: production

WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.

Use a production WSGI server instead.

* Debug mode: on

* Restarting with stat

* Debugger is active!

* Debugger PIN:

* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Also when I run `netstats -q` in my windows machine I can see a process listening to a port:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:5005 SOMETHING LISTENING
```

Seems to be an issue with the network. Even creating a simple HTTP server in my pc does not let any external traffic to reach.But It works if I switch the receiver and requestor (making my local send a request to another pc in my network with a HTTP Server)

Comment: Are u testing from another machine ?

Comment: yeah im trying to  hit from another machine in my LAN, which I can connect using mstc.

When I hit from the other machine I substitute the 0.0.0.0 for the ip that comes inside ipv4 when I run ipconfig.

Comment: Can u open the page using external IP on local machine? ( The machine u are running your flask app on )

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the network firewall, some directioning rules that were fixed once we change some configurations in the firewall